# Scheme remove left and right children if they are null

Tags: scheme

I am trying to write scheme code (DrRaket or MIT) that remove left and right children if they are null.

;;definition of make-tree;;

```
(define (make-tree entry left right)
  (list entry left right))
```

;;input tree;;

```
(define tree (8 (5 (2 () ()) (4 () ())) (3 () (10 () ()))))
```

if I do (print tree)  suppose to change the input tree to

;;expected output;;

```
(8 (5 (2)(4)) (3 () (10)))
```

;;

```
(define (print tree)
  (cond ((and (null? (cadr tree)) (null? (caddr tree)))
         (cons (car tree) '())
         (make-tree (car tree) (cadr tree) (caddr tree))
         (print tree)
         )))
```

But I get linefeed after attempting (print tree).  Could someone help me get the expected output?

In reply to soegaard 33's solution

```
(define (prune tree)
  (cond tree
    ((list x '()  '())    (list x))
    ((list x left '())    (list (prune left) (list x)))
    ((list x '()  right)  (list              (list x) (prune right)))
    ((list x left right)  (make-tree x (prune left) (prune right)))))

Output
Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.1.1 [3m].
Language: R5RS; memory limit: 128 MB.
. tree: bad syntax in: tree
>
```

Comment: Do you need to construct the tree without empty leaves or do you just need to print it?

Comment: @soegarrd: I just need to print out.  It should not alter the structure of the tree in any way.  I have to use make-tree through.

Comment: @soegaard used `match` and **not** `cond` in his solution. They do not do the same! Also know that `match` only works in `#!racket` unless you change the patterns to `mlist` for `#!r6rs`.

Comment: Your `(define tree (8 ...))` can't possibly work - `8` is not a function.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses `match` from Racket.

```
(define (prune tree)
  (match tree
    [(list x '()  '())    (list x)]
    [(list x left '())    (list (prune left) (list x))]
    [(list x '()  right)  (list              (list x) (prune right))]
    [(list x left right)  (make-tree x (prune left) (prune right))]))
```

The tree has four different shapes.

Each clause handles a different shape.

If you can't use `match` change it to a `cond` with four cases.

Update:

```
(match tree
  ((list x '()  '())    (list x))
  ...
  ...)
```

becomes

```
(cond 
  ((and (list? tree) 
        (null? (cadr tree))     ; the second element is '()
        (null? (caddr tree)))   ; the third  element is '()
   (list x))
  ...
  ...)
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution.  I got the following message from DrRacket  "Welcome to DrRacket, version 6.1.1 [3m].
Language: R5RS; memory limit: 128 MB.
. read: illegal use of open square bracket"

Comment: Yes. This is a `#lang racket` solution. You can use `cond` instead of `match` in R5RS, but you need to rewrite the left hand sides of the clauses.

Comment: Also change all [] to ().

Comment: Please take a look at the updated version of your solution I have tired.  I got error of syntax relate. Do you see something wrong?

Comment: If you use `cond` you need to rewrite the left hand sides. See the updated answer.